# LDAP authentication for a HTML/JavaScript application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, ldap, authorization

I am building a HTML/JavaScript application using AngularJS. It doesn't have a backend except some Perl scripts that spit JSON through a URL through which I display the data. One of the pages on this dashboard needs privileged access for which I had to add LDAP authorization.

The application is deployed on a WAMP server. Active directory is being used in the organization; but I am not quite sure how to establish the authentication in a pure html application without a backend. What is the usual process followed to handle such authorizations and how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should write a web service (REST) in any language you want (JAVA C# PHP Node.js ...) who autenticate against your Open LDAP server and you'll consume it in AngularJS. 
It's quite a classic problem.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a perfect candidate for [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/). Use one of the many available libraries available.